# Download video or audio file from server on my android application

Tags: android

i am developing an android application to download a video file from my server using a link.
and i am doing it using intent call to the browser.
opening the link using any browser opens the file and starts playing it.
but what i want to do is to start downloading the video to sdcard.
video format is .mp4
and the way i am calling opening the link in my app is like this:

```
Intent browserIntent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(myUrl));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Comment: i need another way not using intent, maybe something like httpclient

Comment: first try [this](http://dharmendra4android.blogspot.in/2011/07/download-files-using-intent.html) i think this will help you more

Comment: thanks for your replay, what i am looking for is download file without using intents.

Comment: now i am using download manager class

Answer (score 2):

Great! your found the best answer, anyway, i used below code to download videos from servers. you can refer either. Thanks.

```
class DownloadFileFromURL extends AsyncTask<Object, String, Integer> {



        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();


        }


        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
            super.onCancelled();

        }

        /**
         * Downloading file in background thread
         * */
        @Override
        protected Integer doInBackground(Object... params) {

            try {

                URL url = new URL((String) params[1]);

                name = ((String) params[1]).substring(((String) params[1])
                        .lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                // Log.v("log_tag", "name Substring ::: " + name);
                URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
                conection.connect();
                // getting file length
                int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

                // input stream to read file - with 8k buffer
                InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),
                        8192);
                File download = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        + "/download/");
                if (!download.exists()) {
                    download.mkdir();
                }
                String strDownloaDuRL = download + "/" + name;
                Log.v("log_tag", " down url   " + strDownloaDuRL);
                FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(strDownloaDuRL);

                byte data[] = new byte[1024];

                long total = 0;

                }
                // flushing output
                output.flush();

                // closing streams
                output.close();
                input.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            }
            return 0;

        }




        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

         // Do after downloaded file

        }

    }
```