# Is it possible to download videos from server url and and save it into that application itself

Tags: android, web-services, server, video-streaming, android-download-manager

Is it possible to download videos from a server and save it into an Android application itself(like save offline). I don't want to see downloaded videos in gallery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible . Check this [Download video or audio file from server on my android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112105/download-video-or-audio-file-from-server-on-my-android-application) .  Add a file named "`.nomedia`" on the folder where you are downloading the video to and it will hide your videos from gallery.